# Django: Facebook comments integration

Tags: django, facebook

I want Facebook comments integration on Django site, what should I use to integrate Facebook comments into a page?

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done via javascript. Just add the Facebook SDK and add the comments at the bottom of your template. Just make sure to have some sort of slug to uniquely identify the page

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
};

(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>

...

<div
   class="fb-comments" 
   data-href="{{ my_object.slug }}" 
   data-num-posts="2" 
   data-width="470"></div>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: No more channel file:

>  **Changed browser requirements for the JavaScript SDK**

>  In order for the JavaScript SDK to be able to communicate with Facebook, we now require either native support for HTML5 postMessage, or support for Flash, minimum version 8.0.24. As part of this change, we are no longer supporting the use of the channelUrl initialization option to provide a fallback mechanism.

Source: [Facebook Blog, Nov 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/21/platform-updates--new-design-for-follow-button-and-like-box--ios-sdk-improvements-and-more/)